# SQL row_number() between values

Tags: sql-server

I have a table where I keep my vehicles rides.

I have started and ended columns and I extracted how much time my cars spend between rides.

Now I'm trying to count the trips between every charge

Current result:

[image: Current result]

Expected result:

[image: Expected result]

I've tried with row_number() and I wasn't able to do it

```
SELECT 
    t1.*,
    DATEDIFF (MINUTE, t1.started, t2.started)
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         id, started, ended, battery_level, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY started) AS rowid
     FROM
         vehicle_trips
     WHERE
         id = '1') t1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         id, started, ended, battery_level,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY started_at) AS rowid
     FROM
         vehicle_trips
     WHERE
         id = '1') t2 ON t1.rowid = t2.rowid - 1
```

Comment: provide sample data and tag with correct DBMS, not both MySQL and SQL server. It should be one dbms

Comment: How do you define "charge"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A charge is anytime the battery level increases from the prior level.

```
with chrg as (
    select *,
       case when battery_level -
           -- treat the first row as a logical charge
           coalesce(lag(battery_level) over (partition by id order by started), -1) > 0
           then 1 else 0 end as isCharge
    from vehicle_trips
), grp as (
    select *, sum(isCharge) over (partition by id order by started) as grp
    from chrg
)
select *, row_number() over (partition by id, grp order by started) as "order"
from grp
```

Comment: Thank you! Problem solved :D
I have integrated your solution in my query and works perfectly

Comment: @johnnyReed I just made a correction to the `row_number()`'s `partition by`. Make sure you add `id` in there so it works when you have more than all 1s in your table.

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that "charge" means that the battery level is 100, then use a cumulative sum to identify the charge periods and then use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by id, grp order by started) as trip_number
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when battery_level = 100 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id order by started) as grp
      from vehicle_trips vt
     ) vt;
```

For the more general situation of budget just going up, you can use `lag()`:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by id, grp order by started) as trip_number
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when battery_level < prev_battery_level then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by id order by started) as grp
      from (select vt.*,
                   lag(battery_level) over (partition by id order by started) as prev_battery_level
            from vehicle_trips vt
           ) vt
     ) vt
```